# Get stored WiFi passwords for disconnected WiFi adapter

Tags: windows, wifi

For example, if I have USB WiFi adapter, I can store password from some WiFi network and get it using `netsh wlan show profile ProfileName key=clear` command.
But after I disconnect USB WiFi adapter the above command will show error:

`There is no wireless interface on the system.`

How can I get stored passwords for disconnected WiFi device? May be they are stored somewhere in registry? Passwords are definitely stored somewhere, because if I connect my USB WiFi adapter again - then `netsh` command begins to work.

I did not found how to get this information using [Windows API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/nativewifi/wireless-user-interface-apis) either.